# Why does SQL percentage calculation return zero percent for something that shouldn't equal zero?

Tags: sql-server, statistics

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT
  _column_ as segment,
  count(*) as count,
  (Count(_column_)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From _table_)) as percentage
FROM
  _table_
GROUP BY _column_
ORDER BY _column_
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{ segment: null,  count: 308,    percentage: 0 },
 { segment: 1,     count: 16346,  percentage: 40 },
 { segment: 2,     count: 13186,  percentage: 32 },
 { segment: 3,     count: 10309,  percentage: 25 }]
```

Why is it that this query returns 0% for the `null` segment?

Comment: It is performing integer division. Try * 100.0 instead.

Comment: `COUNT()` returns an `INT`, `COUNT()*100` is still an `INT`. If `COUNT(*)*100` is smaller than `SELECT COUNT() FROM table` then since it performs an integer division it will return `0`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos this change causes segments 1, 2, and 3 to now have decimals, but still `null` has 0 percent

Comment: @Lamak interesting, so what should I do instead to make it properly produce a non-zero?

Comment: What @Kristian said should work. If it doesn't, then you are most likely not getting a count of 308 for that segment. And really, your query shows the same, that's because you are using `COUNT(_column_)`, and `_column_` is `NULL`

Comment: ^ I am kristian. Kristian is me. =D

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant @GiorgosBetsos

Comment: change count(_column_) into count(*) and multiply with 100.0 and your good

Comment: @Aツ add that as a answer, and I will upvote it and accept it.